# Next.js 13 not rendering on the browser

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am starting a Next.js 13 Application and my React component is not rendering on the browser even though global.css styles seem to be rendering. I've tried a different browser with no success.

```
// app/page.tsx
import React from 'react'

const page = () => {
  return (
    <div>page</div>
  )
}

export default page
```

[image: my code, files and folders]

Answer (score 0):

Name of your component should start with Uppercase, so it should be Page (file name is okay, but component name isn't).

Hope it helps.

Comment: That didn't help. Thanks.

Comment: Somehow I had removed children from layout.tsx HTML code.